# C# - Convert a string of Key value pair separated by '=' to Dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I'm extracting data from an API which gives me some information in JSON. However, one of the values gives me:

```
{X0=80,X1=80,X2=80,X3=80,X4=80,X5=80,X6=80,X7=80,X8=80,X9=80,X10=80,X11=80,X12=80,X13=80,X14=80,X15=80,X16=80,X17=80,X18=80,X19=80,X20=80,X21=80,X22=80,X23=80,X24=80,X25=80,X26=80,X27=80,X28=80,X29=80,X30=80,X31=80,X32=80,X33=80,X34=80,X35=80,X36=80,X37=80,X38=80,X39=80,X40=80,X41=80,X42=80,X43=80,X44=80,X45=80,X46=80,X47=80,X48=80,X49=80,X50=80,X51=80,X52=80,X53=80,X54=80,X55=80,X56=80,X57=80,X58=80,X59=80,X60=80,X61=80,X62=80}
```

I am trying to decode this for use in a C# Console Application (.NET).
My main question is, what would be the best way to extract this string into a dictionary or array? I am not sure if I have worded this correctly, so please correct me if I'm wrong!

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use *Linq* with `Trim`, `Split`, `Select`, `ToDictionary`

```
var result = json.Trim('{', '}')
                 .Split(',')
                 .Select(x => x.Split('='))
                 .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => int.Parse(x[1]));

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\r\n", result.Select(x => x.Key + " : " + x.Value)));
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8IMLG3)

And just because i'm bored

## Benchmarks

```
Mode             : Release (64Bit)
Test Framework   : .NET Framework 4.7.1

Operating System : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version          : 10.0.17134

CPU Name         : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz
Description      : Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9

Cores (Threads)  : 4 (8)      : Architecture  : x64
Clock Speed      : 3901 MHz   : Bus Speed     : 100 MHz
L2Cache          : 1 MB       : L3Cache       : 8 MB

Benchmarks Runs : Inputs (1) * Scales (3) * Benchmarks (3) * Runs (100) = 900
```

**Results**

```
--- Random Set ----------------------------------------------------------------------
| Value       |   Average |   Fastest |      Cycles |    Garbage | Test |      Gain |
--- Scale 100 -------------------------------------------------------- Time 0.229 ---
| Split       |  0.058 ms |  0.043 ms |     207,064 |  48.000 KB | Base |    0.00 % |
| JsonReplace |  0.077 ms |  0.064 ms |     273,556 |  24.000 KB | Pass |  -32.38 % |
| Regex       |  0.270 ms |  0.235 ms |     950,504 |  80.000 KB | Pass | -364.87 % |
--- Scale 1,000 ------------------------------------------------------ Time 0.633 ---
| Split       |  0.490 ms |  0.446 ms |   1,718,180 | 495.102 KB | Base |    0.00 % |
| JsonReplace |  0.671 ms |  0.596 ms |   2,352,043 | 195.078 KB | Pass |  -36.86 % |
| Regex       |  2.544 ms |  2.293 ms |   8,897,994 | 731.125 KB | Pass | -419.00 % |
--- Scale 10,000 ----------------------------------------------------- Time 5.005 ---
| Split       |  5.247 ms |  4.673 ms |  18,363,748 |   4.843 MB | Base |    0.00 % |
| JsonReplace |  6.782 ms |  5.488 ms |  23,721,593 |   1.829 MB | Pass |  -29.25 % |
| Regex       | 31.840 ms | 27.008 ms | 111,277,134 |   6.637 MB | Pass | -506.80 % |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Data**

```
private string GenerateData(int scale)
{
   var ary = Enumerable.Range(0, scale)
                       .Select(x => $"X{x}={Rand.Next()}")
                       .ToList();

   return $"{{{string.Join(",", ary)}}}";
}
```

**Split**

```
public class Split : Benchmark<string, Dictionary<string,int>>
{
   protected override Dictionary<string,int> InternalRun()
   {
      return Input.Trim('{', '}')
                       .Split(',')
                       .Select(x => x.Split('='))
                       .ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => int.Parse(x[1]));
   }
}
```

**Regex**

Credited to *emsimpson92* using `Cast`

```
public class Regex : Benchmark<string, Dictionary<string,int>>
{
   protected override Dictionary<string,int> InternalRun()
   {
      var regex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("(?<key>[^,]+)=(?<value>[^,]+)");
      var matchCollection = regex.Matches(Input.Trim('{', '}'));
      return matchCollection.Cast<Match>()
                     .ToDictionary(
                         x => x.Groups["key"].Value,
                         x => int.Parse(x.Groups["value"].Value));
   }
}
```

**JsonReplace**

Credited to *Hanzalah Adalan* Modified to work with `string.replace`

```
public unsafe class JsonReplace : Benchmark<string, Dictionary<string,int>>
{
   protected override Dictionary<string,int> InternalRun()
   {
     return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,int>>(Input.Replace("=", ":"));
   }
}
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[String.Trim Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns a new string in which all leading and trailing occurrences of
>   a set of specified characters from the current String object are
>   removed.

[String.Split Method (String[], StringSplitOptions)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Splits a string into substrings based on the strings in an array. You
>   can specify whether the substrings include empty array elements.

[Enumerable.Select Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

[Enumerable.ToDictionary Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549277(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Creates a Dictionary from an IEnumerable according to
>   a specified key selector function.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `Regex` The following pattern will capture keys and values in 2 separate groups `(?<key>[^,]+)=(?<value>[^,]+)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qBlF62/23)

Once you have your `MatchCollection`, run a `foreach` loop through it, and add each element to a dictionary.

Comment: "...and then you have two problems."  Seriously though, while this *can* be done with regex it's far from being a good option.  The format is so simple that splitting the strings is almost trivial.  And fast too.

Answer (score 1):

```
Var myAwesomeDictionary = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,string>>(_yourJsonStringHere);
```

Comment: may I know why it didn't work? is it because you doesn't add the NuGet package for the Newtonsoft yet or what type of exception you have? or does it  return null value?

Comment: the equals sign, i added a version with string.replace to my benchmark.

Comment: I credited you, let me know if you can get it to work without replace